# How to add snippets through custom extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I want to make all my tools into one extension including snippets, I know how to add snippets by steps operations, and how to make an extension, but how can we add snippets by making and installing an extension?

Comment: you can add a contribution point for a snippets file, you can add snippets in CompletionItemProvider and you can add a snippet in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add contribution point 'snippets' in `package.json` .

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "snippets": [
      {
        "language": "go",
        "path": "./snippets/go.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- The `language` attribute is the language identifier.
- The `path` is the relative path to the snippet file.

Here are official references : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.snippets

**or**

You can also choose `New Code Snippets` when creating an extension project with `yo code` command. This way is useful to create an extension just for snippets.

Hope this helps!